# <HTML5> I want to make a button that I will be using in many pages

Tags: html, css, class, button, dreamweaver

I've got a bunch of pictures and I want to make a series of pages with 3 buttons: back, next and Home. Is there anyway to acomplish this using classes? 
I gave it a shot and this is what came up with:
HTML

```
<div id = "back" class="btn_back">
```

CSS

```
.btn_back {
background-color:#C00; 
display:block; 
width:110px; 
height: 20px; 
text-align:center, justify; }
```

Comment: And what's the problem ?

Comment: CSS is for styling content .. it has nothing to do with functionality

Comment: I think you can try to build a menu for your site. Try to find examples how can be do it.

Comment: `<div id = "back" class="btn_back">` There should be no spaces between id="

Comment: @Pedro, you could please clarify exactly what you're asking here?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a `div` as an interactive element instead of an `a` or `input` element?

Comment: I was using the div as an interactive element. Didn't know it couldn't be. I am now using the `a` thx

Comment: @Pedro Before you go any further, buy yourself this book: http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access forward and back, you'll need DOM control. You can do it through javascript. Alternatively, you could link each page independently where back takes you to the previous page and forward takes you to the unseen page.

Say this is page 2

```
<a href="1.html">Back</a>
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
<a href="3.html">Forward</a>
```

Your question is not so easy to answer, as there are many methods to do what you are asking.

Comment: That was exactly what i wanted to do. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have your button! Congrats... Now try to actually use backwards and forward buttons. You can use a combination of html and javascript.

In HTML, you can set links with a relativity to "next" and "prev". All this does however, is links the pages together, usually used for blogs. You'll want to use javascript to dynamically update what each button does when it is clicked.

HTML sample:

```
<link rel="next" href="next_page.html">
<link rel="prev" href="prev_page.html">
```

JavaScript sample:

```
var back = document.getElementsById("back")[0];
var next = document.getElementsById("next")[0];
back.onClick = function() { window.location = 'prev_page.html' }
next.onClick = function() { window.location = 'next_page.html' }
```

However, take note, the HTML and Javascript samples I provided aren't related to each other. But you could set the `window.location` to a variable defined by the value of `link next` and `link prev`. By this time, you can google on how to do this.

Comment: Why are you using a `link` tag? What on earth is going on with this Javascript? And why has this answer got one upvote...?

Comment: Well, it has got a upvote because it is in fact a good answer, not the one I was looking for, but indeed helpful.

Comment: Wrong choice of HTML element `<link>` (should've used `<a>`) instead, and the javascript makes no sense at all - unless you are accessing browser history.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little late, but the `link` element can actually signify previous and next pages when put inside the `head` element (do **not** use this in the context of setting a clickable link, this is for setting relations). And @DjangoReinhardt, the javascript uses a query to target his `next` and `back` buttons, then once clicked, it sets a `window.location`. Nothing fancy.

Comment: @Jacedc As Terry pointed out, the Javascript makes absolutely no sense at all. If you're storing the next and previous in a link in the head, why don't you refer to them when you change the window.location? Plus, your Javascript doesn't actually do anything: http://jsfiddle.net/VWyC3/

Comment: Well, as I said, "*However, take note, the HTML and Javascript samples I provided aren't related to each other. But you [could] set the `window.location` to a variable defined by the value of `link next` and `link prev`. But by this time, you can google on how to do this*" The JavaScript and HTML aren't meant to communicate with each other. The `link`s don't really do anything except provide relativity for crawlers. Keep in mind, my `rel` attributes are not `id`s, which explains why the javascript and html aren't related. The `onClick` in javascript is meant for a `input/button` element or `a`

Comment: Keep in mind, the question was very broad to begin with. If we would've known that the OP just wanted links to `page1`, `page2`, and the homepage, we could have *all* answered with anchor tags, then the mods could have closed this question as too localized or non-constructive.

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way a dynamic answer, but it will work for a beginner.  The below assumes you are on page 3.

- Previous
- Home
- Previous

CSS:

ul li { display: inline-block; }

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing (functionally) wrong with the code you posted. Did you remember to include your stylesheet?
If the functionality is not working, that would be a `javascript` question, not `CSS`, and we would need to see your current `javascript` code.